# Angular: How to use a Component as route entry and in another component's template

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-components, angular-template

I'm facing the following issue:

We have different components, which are loaded in an iframe inside our application. Now I want to use one of these components in an embedded way via selector tag, too.

So given is a ComponentA:

```
@Component(
    {
        selector: 'a',
        templateUrl: './a.component.html',
.....
```

in ModuleA:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AComponent],
              imports: [
                  RouterModule.forChild(routes),
              ],
exports: [AComponent]
})
export class AModule { }
```

This ComponentA is lazy loaded via routing in app.routing.module.ts:

```
{
    path: 'a',
    loadChildren: () => import('./a/a.module')
        .then((m) => m.AModule),
},
```

The other ComponentB in ModuleB.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [BComponent],
              imports: [
                  RouterModule.forChild(routes),
                  AModule,
              ],
exports: [BComponent]
})
export class BModule { }
```

This ComponentB is lazy loaded via routing in app.routing.module.ts:

```
{
    path: 'b',
    loadChildren: () => import('./b/b.module')
        .then((m) => m.BModule),
},
```

The Main AppComponent is just a simple router-outlet

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Now I want to use the ComponentA inside ComponentB's template (b.component.html):

```
<div>Content ComponentB</div>
<div><a></a></div>
```

What I encounter is, that the RouterModule.forChild(routes) in AModule is performing a routing to the ComponentA so my result body just contains ComponentA:

```
<a></a>
```

When I remove the RouterModule.forChild(routes) I can use the componentn in html template as usal, but then I can't access the Component directly via routing(app/#a)

I could build a moduleC which is handling routing for componentA and remove the routing from moduleA and embedd componentA in both modules (moduleC and moduleB), but that feels a litte bit dirty.

Is there any chance to use a Component inside a module in both ways at the same time?

Greetings
Gemorra

Answer (score 0):

If someone get's stuck in the same situation, here is my workaround using a wrapper-module:

This module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: A},
];

@NgModule({
              imports: [
                  RouterModule.forChild(routes),
                  AModule
              ],
    exports: []
})
export class AWrapperModule{ }
```

is just for routing from angular-routes

```
{
    path: 'a',
    loadChildren: () => import('./a/a-wrapper.module')
        .then((m) => m.AWrapperModule),
},
```

to component A, which has to be changed (removing the routing stuff):

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AComponent],
exports: [AComponent]
})
export class AModule { }
```

That's it. Now I can use module A in another html template via selector tag and 'directly' through routing. I don't know if there is an easier way, but I didn't find any settigs or configuration for my problem. Using one additonal module, which only has the module-class seems to be fine.